# Trying to combine 2 data.frame on R with rbind and getting a error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

Tags: r, rbind

Trying to combine 2 data.frame on R with rbind

`data.combined <- rbind(train, test.survived)`

Getting a error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

Comment: Check the column names of both datasets.  It may need to be matching for `rbind` to work.  Try `colnames(test.survived) <- colnames(train)` assuming that both datasets have the same number of columns and are in the same order.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for this problem is the following codeline while adding a survived variable

Use this:

```
test.survived <- data.frame(Survived = rep("None", nrow(test)), test[,])
```

instead of this:

```
test.survived <- data.frame(survived = rep("None", nrow(test)), test[,])
```

The only difference is the capital "S" for Survived row as the data is given in that manner

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
test.survived <- data.frame(Survived= rep("None",nrow(test)),test[,])
data.combined <- rbind(train,test.survived)
```

The col name in train.csv file is "Survived" and you have added a col name "survived" to test.survived and on combining these two files it will throw an error because col names are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your data form to a matrix form. Then you can use the "rbind()" function. After that, you can change it to the original form. The sample code is shown below.

`train <-as.matrix(train)
test.survived <- as.matrix(test.survived)`

`data.combined <- data.frame()
data.combined <- rbind(train, test.survived)`

`data.combined <- as.data.frame(data.combined)`

Answer (score -1):

try colNames = FALSE and its done !

Comment: You mean `data.combined <- rbind(train, test.survived, colNames = FALSE)`? Did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

It denotes the complete test data set with all columns and all rows

Also instead of using Survived go with survived in the train data also that should solved the problem